# Having some issue in the Search of Mysqli database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issue in the `Mysqli + PHP` Search functionality.
I have some records having `performerName`  = `JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE A` Some Records have `JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL` And Some have only `JOANNE GRACE`.

What I want, If I Search with query.

```
$query = "JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE A";

SELECT * FROM `sections` WHERE `performerName` LIKE '%JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE A%'
```

I want to get All with matching words from query  `JOANNE GRACE` and `JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL`
But This query gives all having complete name.  `JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE A`

I have tried with many ways in Mysql. It searches the whole query what i have given above.
But I want it should match the all records even some records have 2 words from that query or 3 words from that query.

I tried `REGEX`, `LIKE%%` But not worked. It matches Full Query. Is there any solution for it

Comment: Is it a static query or dynamic that changes search parameters depending on the query?

Comment: Have you tried using the OR keyword? e.g. where field like 'ex1' or field like 'ex2'. Or using IN().

Comment: @PadraigD It is Dynamic query. Changes the search parameters

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there's a **good** solution where you would be able to have your query in the format:

```
SELECT * FROM `sections` WHERE `performerName` LIKE ?
```

However, it's a fairly simple task to match any of the words in the `$performerName` string using `LIKE` and `OR`.

**mysqli**

```
$performerName = "JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE A";                     // Input

$search_string = preg_replace("/(\w+)/i", "%$1%", $performerName);    // Surround each word with "%" ready for the LIKE clause
$search_array  = explode(" ", $search_string);                        // Split input into array of search terms

$option_type = str_repeat("s", count($search_array));                 // Count how many search terms there are and output the value types for mysqli->bind_param
$option_list = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($search_array), "( performerName LIKE ?)"));    // Convert the array to a string for the SQL

// $option_type == "ssssss";
// $option_list == "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM sections WHERE ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? )";

$sql   = "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM sections WHERE {$option_list}";    // SQL statement merging with $option_list
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);                    // Prepare the query
$query->bind_param($var_type, ...$search_array);    // Bind parameters to query
$query->execute();                                  // Execute the query
$query->store_result();                             // Catch the result
$query->bind_result($field1, $field2, $field3);     // Bind the columns to variables

while($query->fetch()){
     // Do something with each row of returned data...

     echo "Name: {$field1}<br>";    // Example, echo name of performer (field_1)
}
```

**PDO [1]**

```
$performerName = "JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE";

$search_string = preg_replace("/(\w+)/i", "%$1%", $performerName);
$search_array  = explode(" ", $search_string);

$option_list = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($search_array), "( name LIKE ? )"));

// $option_list == "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM sections WHERE ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? )";

$sql   = "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM sections WHERE {$option_list}";    // SQL statement merging with $option_list
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($search_array);
$query->bindColumn('name', $name);

while($query->fetch()){
     // Do something with each row of returned data...

     echo "Name: {$field1}<br>";    // Example, echo name of performer (field_1)
}
```

**PDO [2]**

```
$performerName = "JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE";

$search_string = preg_replace("/(\w+)/i", "%$1%", $performerName);
$search_array  = explode(" ", $search_string);

$option_list = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($search_array), "( name LIKE ? )"));

// $option_list == "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM sections WHERE ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? ) OR ( performerName LIKE ? )";

$sql   = "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM sections WHERE {$option_list}";    // SQL statement merging with $option_list
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($search_array);

while($record = $query->fetchObject()){
     // Do something with each row of returned data...

     echo "Name: {$record->field_1}<br>";    // Example, echo name of performer (field_1)
}
```

Of course you could easily make this more advanced with `REGEXP`.

**Some Caveats**

`field_name LIKE '%WORD%'` will match `WORD` with any characters surrounding it. That means you may get some unexpected results...

```
Search String        Matches

%the%                "the", " the ", "other", "clothes"
%app%                "app", "apple", "schnapps"
```

Comment: @Dharman Perhaps in this example it is _easier_ to use `PDO`. However, generally speaking I would suggest it's not that **PDO** is easier than **mysqli**; more that it's just a different approach. One example where it would be _much easier_ to use `mysqli` would be if we were attempting to validate integers against the database. To do so with `PDO` you'd need a new line of code for every integer? Where as with `mysqli` it remains one AND the same line that you would be used to using... Both have their place and as such I have added some PDO examples as well! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using PDO. I changed the variable value and it gives 3 rows. Please try this

```
<?php

//Here this is a connect database

$host_name = "localhost";
$db_name = "stackoverflow";
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$db_name", $user_name, $password);

$name = 'JOANNE GRACE%'; //Search this name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search_name WHERE name LIKE ?";
$select = $conn->prepare($sql);
$select->execute([$name]);

$row = $select->rowCount();

echo "The row is : ".$row;
```

OUTPUT:

> The row is : 3

Comment: Dear I want the Query Same length
$query = "JOANNE GRACE SCHOOL OF DANCE A";
I know if I short down the JOANNE GRACE it will search what I want. But My Dynamic Query is not changeable